# mod_rewrite not appending queries

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a site where I am trying to rewrite search/ks3/7/example-topic to search.php?ks=ks3&year=7&topic=example-topic

I am using apache mod_rewrite and my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9-+) search.php?ks=$1&year=$2&topic=$3 [R=301,L]
```

However, when I browse to search/ks3/7/example my php $_GET['ks'], $_GET['topic'] and $_GET['year'] contain no data.

My apache error log shows errors in the PHP "undefined index ks" etc.

My rewrite log (which is set to a verbosity of 9) shows:

```
192.168.0.171 - - [08/Jan/2012:13:11:46 +0000] [192.168.0.10/sid#7ff3cc9b7460][rid#7ff3c65f90a0/initial] (3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] add path info postfix: /data/shared/chemistry/search.php -> /data/shared/chemistry/search.php/ks3/7/example-topic
192.168.0.171 - - [08/Jan/2012:13:11:46 +0000] [192.168.0.10/sid#7ff3cc9b7460][rid#7ff3c65f90a0/initial] (3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] strip per-dir prefix: /data/shared/chemistry/search.php/ks3/7/example-topic -> search.php/ks3/7/example-topic
192.168.0.171 - - [08/Jan/2012:13:11:46 +0000] [192.168.0.10/sid#7ff3cc9b7460][rid#7ff3c65f90a0/initial] (3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] applying pattern '^search/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9-+)$' to uri 'search.php/ks3/7/example-topic'
192.168.0.171 - - [08/Jan/2012:13:11:46 +0000] [192.168.0.10/sid#7ff3cc9b7460][rid#7ff3c65f90a0/initial] (1) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] pass through /data/shared/chemistry/search.php
192.168.0.171 - - [08/Jan/2012:13:11:46 +0000] [192.168.0.10/sid#7ff3cc9b7460][rid#7ff3c65f00a0/subreq] (1) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] pass through /data/shared/chemistry/ks3
```

and my apache virtual hosts file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin powerj96@hotmail.co.uk

    DocumentRoot /data/shared/chemistry
    <Directory /data/shared/chemistry/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Mod_Rewrite is definitely working. I have tried the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^google http://www.google.com [R=301,L]
```

and this works.

I also run 4 other virtual hosts on the server, 3 of which are just websites and 1 is transmission's web interface.

I am running Ubuntu Server 11.11

EDIT:

I think the problem may be to do with running reverse proxy alongside this. for example, if reverse proxy is changing 192.168.0.10:81 (address of my server and port 81 vhost) to transmission/web then the fact that transmission is running at 192.168.0.10/transmission/web, which is both a vhost and a subdirectory of the site which is running at 192.168.0.10/ (the one in question on this post), may be causing conflicts in the rewrite module. Do you have any ideas of a solution to this if you think  it may be the problem.

EDIT:

This is the complete log for everything that happens when I click the link search/ks3/7/example-topic

```
(1) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] pass through /data/shared/chemistry/search.php
(3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] add path info postfix: /data/shared/chemistry/search.php -> /data/shared/chemistry/search.php/ks3/7/example-topic
(3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] strip per-dir prefix: /data/shared/chemistry/search.php/ks3/7/example-topic -> search.php/ks3/7/example-topic
(3) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] applying pattern '^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)' to uri 'search.php/ks3/7/example-topic'
(1) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] pass through /data/shared/chemistry/search.php
(1) [perdir /data/shared/chemistry/] pass through /data/shared/chemistry/ks3
```

EDIT:

I have realised the source of the problem after looking at that log file. For some reason apache is rewriting search/ks3/7/example-topic to search.php/ks3/7/example-topic before it applies my rewrite, therefore search/ks3/7/example-topic doesn't satisfy the

```
^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

rule. I have changed the rule to

```
^search.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

and this works.

Do you have any idea of how to stop apache rewriting search/ks3/7/example-topic to search.php/ks3/7/example-topic ?

It is working now, after removing the QSA, NC and R=301 options.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewritelog doesn't tell much. Remove IP information at the beginning (who cares?).  And add the beginning of rewrite (= tell us what is the uri that will be rewritten): take a look at the first line of the following log.

Here's an example of what should be more helpful:

---

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /robots.txt
(3) applying pattern '(.*)setup.php' to uri '/robots.txt'
(3) applying pattern '(.*)admin(.*)' to uri '/robots.txt'
(3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/robots.txt'
(4) RewriteCond: input='www.papdevis.com' pattern='!(papdevis)' [NC] => not-matched
(3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/robots.txt'
(4) RewriteCond: input='www.papdevis.com' pattern='(.*)\.(com|net|org|eu)' [NC] =>     matched
(2) rewrite '/robots.txt' -> 'http://www.papdevis.fr/robots.txt'
(2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.papdevis.fr/robots.txt
(1) escaping http://www.papdevis.fr/robots.txt for redirect
(1) redirect to http://www.papdevis.fr/robots.txt [REDIRECT/301]
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri / 
(3) applying pattern '(.*)setup.php' to uri '/'
(3) applying pattern '(.*)admin(.*)' to uri '/'
(3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/'
(4) RewriteCond: input='www.papdevis.com' pattern='!(papdevis)' [NC] => not-matched
(3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/'
(4) RewriteCond: input='www.papdevis.com' pattern='(.*)\.(com|net|org|eu)' [NC] => matched
(2) rewrite '/' -> 'http://www.papdevis.fr/'
(2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.papdevis.fr/
(1) escaping http://www.papdevis.fr/ for redirect
(1) redirect to http://www.papdevis.fr/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

---

Rewrite from:

```
search/ks3/7/example-topic
```

to

```
search.php?ks=ks3&year=7&topic=example-topic
```

And your `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9+)/(a-zA-Z0-9-+) \
    search.php?ks=$1&year=$2&topic=$3 [R=301,L]
```

It will never work... try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) \
    search.php?ks=$1&year=$2&topic=$3 [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

... or maybe how about taking everything *but* the slash? This may look like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) \
    search.php?ks=$1&year=$2&topic=$3 [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

Please tell me if this works.

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: This doesn't work. I have turned my rewrite log on, which you can see in the initial post.

Comment: Please check out the edit I have put on, this may help to understand the problem.

Comment: Updated my answer, with a question in my answer ;)